# tableview sent me an error when I tried to present a uiview in front of it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode11.3

I'm new with Xcode and Swift, following a tutorial and I found a problem when I called a UIView in front of a tableview so the user can create something new

NOTE: I already tried what this **[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)** shows with no luck to resolve my issue

I am using Xcode 11.3.1 and Swift

This is my code

Channel Model

```
import Foundation

struct Channel : Decodable {
    public private(set) var channelTitle: String!
    public private(set) var channelDescription: String!
    public private(set) var id: String!
}
Class ChannelCell

import UIKit

class ChannelCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var channelName: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        if selected {
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2).cgColor
        } else {
            self.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        }
    }

    func configureCell(channel: Channel) {
        let title = channel.channelTitle ?? ""
        channelName.text = "#\(title)"
    }
}
```

Channel View Controller

```
import UIKit

class ChannelVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    // Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var loginBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var userImg: CircleImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self <<<<<<<<< here I get the error message ***
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        tableView.dataSource = self


        self.revealViewController()?.rearViewRevealWidth = self.view.frame.size.width - 60
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ChannelVC.userDataDidChange(_:)), name: NOTIF_USER_DATA_DID_CHANGE, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        setupUserInfo()
    }
When I pressed the add channel button comes the problem

    @IBAction func addChannelPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn {
            let addChannel = ChannelVC()
            addChannel.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            present(addChannel, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_LOGIN, sender: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func loginBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn {
            let profile = ProfileVC()
            profile.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
            present(profile, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
           performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_LOGIN, sender: nil)
        }
    }

    @objc func userDataDidChange(_ notif: Notification) {
        setupUserInfo()
    }

    func setupUserInfo() {
        if AuthService.instance.isLoggedIn {
            loginBtn.setTitle(UserDataService.instance.name, for: .normal)
            userImg.image = UIImage(named: UserDataService.instance.avatarName)
            userImg.backgroundColor = UserDataService.instance.returnUIColor(components: UserDataService.instance.avatarColor)
        } else {
            loginBtn.setTitle("Login", for: .normal)
            userImg.image = UIImage(named: "menuProfileIcon")
            userImg.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        }
    }

    // Protocols for UITableViewDataSource
    // # of sections
    // # rows in the section
    // function to setup the cells

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "channelCell", for: indexPath) as? ChannelCell {
I double check the reusable identifier is OK

            let channel = MessageService.instance.channels[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(channel: channel)
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if MessageService.instance.channels.count == 0 {
            tableView.setEmptyView(title: "Message!", message: "You don´t have any channel, create a new one")
        }
        return MessageService.instance.channels.count
    }
}
```

this is the view I want to show when I click on the addChannel function 
[view to present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pe5NQ.jpg)

and this is the debug area
[debug area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3Ncv.jpg)

Comment: [Don't repost questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708351/uitableview-stop-working-after-i-tried-to-show-an-uiview). Did you read the information in the duplicate? If the code crashes at this point then the outlet is not connected.

Comment: The outlet it is connected, before I posted my first question I already tried the info in the link you gave me, I tried not to post any question until I do an extensive reading of other posts. Sorry I didn't want to annoy anyone.

Comment: where did you register `tableView cell`?

Comment: @Vadian I did what you told me and no more error but it didn´t solve my issue.
I think I did not explain myself correctly about this issue, I said I want to show a new UIView when I click on a button. This UIView is a XIB file, I do no know if this new info helps.

Comment: @HabinLama you mean where I declare the cell? I did it with the help of the Main.storyboard I put the tableview and inside this one the table view cell.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a very common mistake. The line

```
let addChannel = ChannelVC()
```

creates a new instance of the controller which is not the instance in the storyboard. Therefore the outlets are not connected and the code crashes.

Replace it with (adjust the identifier accordingly)

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let addChannel = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChannelVC") as! ChannelVC
```

or create a segue.